# Relative path one level up not working in PHP

Tags: php

Currently I have the following structure

httpdocs
- system
- templates

Inside templates I have the following line

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../system/config.php');
```

I get the following error

```
Warning: require_once(/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/templates/../system/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/templates/header.php on line 8

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/templates/../system/config.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/templates/header.php on line 8
```

As you can see in the path it just adds the two dots (../) as if it is part of the path, while I meant it to go up one level. Is there a PHP setting required to support relative paths or something?

I tried all possible variants of the path in- and excluding the **DIR** magic constant to no avail. And yes, config.php is present in system.

Comment: Where is exactly the path of "config.php" ?

Comment: why you are not using it normally require_once(__DIR__.'/system/config.php');

Answer (score 0):

Deeply ashamed. After I moved the page to another server, I had changed the name of the system folder.